# How to recompile css after changing less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I downloaded an HTML/CSS template online that has it's own CSS file running on top of Bootstrap. There are also some less files that contains mixins and variables. After I change the less variables, what do I need to do have my CSS automatically change?

Links to tutorials, etc, are appreciated.

Comment: You need to compile the LESS file, there are tons of ways to do this. You could use a program, an online compiler, a Grunt task, etc. Here's a [LESS to CSS grunt task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) and here's a tutorial detailing how to [set up Grunt to watch for LESS changes](http://jonathanmh.com/make-grunt-watch-for-lesscss-changes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use watch mode, or something like gulp or grunt (see links). They're task runners that will be able to watch your file tree and run tasks based on different changes. Both are really popular, but they each have a different philosophy/paradigm: grunt is more configuration-over-code, while gulp is more code-over-configuration. It just runs generic node modules and makes great use of the streams implemented in Node to achieve concurrency and more-composable tasks.

To compile Less:

```
lessc [option option=parameter ...] <source> [destination]
```

Useful Links:

- http://gulpjs.com/

  - https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md
- http://gruntjs.com/

  - http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
- http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-watch-mode
- http://lesscss.org/#using-less (general less usage)

Answer (score 0):

There are good instructions on simple ways to do it here:
http://lesscss.org/#using-less